# New feature WSL 2 GUI apps is not woking properly :(

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gui, wslg

Microsoft has released a new feature for WSL that runs Linux GUI applications on Windows
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

I followed the steps but I'm not working properly here

I think it's not working, but while writing this post `gedit` unexpectedly opened on my screen
It took a long time to open :(

- WSL: WSL 2
- Distribution: Ubuntu
- Kernel version: 5.10.43

I installed:

- igfx_win_100.9864.exe
- 510.06_gameready_win11_win10-dch_64bit_international.exe
- How can I test if the vGPU is working correctly?
- I don't know what's going on

[Ubuntu GUI Terminal] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWPZr.png)
opens several minutes after trying to open the app

I get this message after opening gedit from the terminal

> (gedit: 867): dconf-WARNING **: 10: 44: 22.415: Failed to commit dconf changes: Error generating command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch = b2041466b29e48f7a6df4883143fed22 --binary-syntax --close- stderr” : Child process terminated with code 1

gedit is working but takes a long time to open

- Edition   Windows 11 Pro Insider Preview
- Version Dev Installed on  ‎10/‎04/‎2021
- OS build  22471.1000
- Experience    Windows Feature
- Experience Pack 1000.22471.1000.0

EDIT 1

With help of our friend things start to working here, gedit opens fastly, nautilus opens fastly and my porpuse Cypress opens okay hsuhsuhs.

But here comes my doubts based on that prints, cypress and other wsl applications should be opened with windows window UI, not?

And cypress performance is a little bit slower, any advise about that?

Maybe I should just install linux here :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2emD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN5u8.png)

Comment: Are you running `Windows 11 version 21H2`?  Windows 10 does not support gWSL applications.  Please edit your question to reflect what version of Windows you are running exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound is not wrong.. but (with that said), I have been running X11 GUI apps under both WSL1 and WSL2 since the early betas.  You just need an X11 server (like VcXSrv or MobaXTerm) and your DISPLAY variable set correctly.  It isn't rocket science.  I do realize that somehow Microsoft has provided the X11 server to forward to but I haven't bothered with it because my existing setup is already borderline perfect.  It is even better than when using X11 forwarding with a remote Linux box.

Comment: The author specifically wants to run the WSL applications natively

Comment: On Windows 11 in a non-GPU-accelerated VM, I get a fairly long launch time for my initial GUI app in a WSL session, but only 20-30 seconds max.  After that they come up within a second or so.  Regarding the `dconf` errors with `gedit`, I don't see that problem myself, but I do get some other warnings out of `gedit`.  That's to be expected since you aren't running a full desktop environment, and some apps are going to give warnings based on a lack of Systemd or other configuration differences.

Comment: @Ramhound I update the post with my windows specs

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I already config that, but I don't like the experience, I need to start VcXSrv every time that I need to use some Linux app, in my case Cypress. And I have some inconsistenses using Cypress, so I tried to use that new feature to run Cypress

Comment: I run VcXSrv in my startup using a config file.  It is allways ready to go and only uses 940k.  I even have shortcuts that fire up X11 GUI apps.  If i doesn't work for you.. ok.. :) just letting you know why I don't need what you are asking for.  @Ramhound, I know what the poster asked, that is why I posted a comment and not an answer but thank you for being such a mega-beast here on SU.  I really do appreciate you.

Comment: @GabrielHoffmanSilva Just curious - Are you running HDD or SDD?  My 20-30 second initial WSGg launch was on an SDD, but then I was doing some maintenance on my older system with an HDD today (not WSLg, though) and was surprised at how much longer my WSL instances took for initial launch.  I might imagine that the WSLg startup might be quite a bit slower on an HDD.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I have an SSD NVMe

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks for the tips, I will try to do that configuration on my system

Comment: @GabrielHoffmanSilva Right, then I can't explain "several minutes" for that initial launch.  Does it launch any faster on the second attempt?  Do other X apps take that long? Also, I know Senor is partial to running VcXSrv.  Assuming you can't get WSLg working well enough (and I wouldn't give up hope yet), and your goal is to run Linux apps on the Windows desktop, then that's the best alternative.  But if you'd like to actually connect to a Linux desktop manager running on WSL, then I'm partial to [using xrdp and Windows Remote Desktop Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68856351/11810933)

Comment: - @NotTheDr01ds any linux gui app takes a long time to open
- I use stopwatch to measure this time and it takes 6min 36sec to open gedit as an example
- I would prefer to use WSLg, after all, I think some Cypress issues I'm facing are caused by VcXSrv

Comment: Anyone knows other way that I can test vGPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same behavior (`gedit` taking several minutes to show up) and fixed to problem following [this post on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/400#issuecomment-941446773):

You basically just have to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0` like this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

If you want the change to be permanent, just put it in you `.bashrc`.

With this, GUI apps from WSL2 should become visible within a couple of seconds.

Comment: I'm getting this error then: `java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.`